# How do I add all include .h files in python directory

Tags: python, pip, pyhook

I am trying to install PyHook using PIP. When I run the command on cmd `pip install pyhook3` I get a C1080 error that tells me there is no such .h file located in my directory. I traced the directory, downloaded the file and it showed me another. I kept doing this until I noticed that there seems to be no end. There seems to be a lot of missing .h files in this includes folder `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include` directory. I don't want to have to download or copy and paste source code for each of these files. Is there any way to get all of them at once, or am I missing the plot entirely?

Comment: you don't have download and copy each file manually. Usually they are a part of a downloadable package that you can install. Installing such a package will usually install all required files for the given library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pyhook](https://pypi.org/project/pyHook) is a Python package with binary dependencies.

When running `pip install pyhook3` you download the source and ask your computer to build it so it can be installed. It thus requires a compiler and a set of header files that are apparently missing for you.

A workaround may be to download manually a compiled version of this package and install it.

You can find on this [page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) a set of binary wheel for pyhook (not pyhook3) for python3 (32 or 64 bit). Once you have downloaded the correct `.whl`, you can install it with `pip install the_filename_you_have_downloaded.whl`